# Change regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following configuration which use a regular expression, basically it says process all files excluding `ComponentA`.

I would need to change the property `regex` so it can can exclude additionally `ComponentB`.

How to change the regex?

```
   {
       regex: /^((?!.*?ComponentA).)*$/
    }
```

Comment: Use: `regex: /^(?!.*(?:ComponentA|ComponentB)).+$/` It will be faster than your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex:

```
/^((?!.*?ComponentA).)*$/
```

asserts that `ComponentA` is not present ahead before matching **each character**. In other words it performs this assertion for each character hence it will perform very slow for bigger strings.

It is better to change this to one time assertion like this:

```
/^(?!.*ComponentA).*$/
```

Since you want to disallow `ComponentB` also so just use an alternation in negative lookahead expression:

```
/^(?!.*(?:ComponentA|ComponentB)).+$/
```